# Why would redirect rules in an nginx.conf file in subfolder be ignored on nginx webserver?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

We implemented dummyimage.com placeholder image generator on a wordpress install. It resides in a subfolder. At the root of the subfolder there is an nginx.conf file that redirects all requests to the folder to "/code.php?x=...." in the same folder.

There is an equivalent ".htaccess" file that has always worked perfectly for years on Apache, but when we switch the webserver to nginx, the redirect rules in the nginx.conf file are being completely ignored.

Why would redirect rules in this nginx.conf file in a subfolder be ignored on nginx webserver ?

I've never really worked with nginx.conf files or redirect rules before. I could not find any answers as to why this is happening. It works perfectly when we switch back to apache (and basically the same rules in .htaccess).

Here are the contents of the nginx.conf file.

```
# Nginx Rewrite rules for dummyimage.com

# URLs like /123x456.jpg will 404 since the image file doesn't actually exist
# We will catch those requests and pass them to code.php and try to render them as images
error_page 404 = @404;
location @404 {
   rewrite (.*) /code.php?x=$request_uri last;
}

# You might have errors if this location block is defined more than once. There can be only one.
location / {

  rewrite ^/([\d].*) /code.php?x=$1$args;

  # Standard Ad Sizes http://www.iab.net/iab_products_and_industry_services/1421/1443/1452

  # Square Pop Up 250x250
  rewrite ^/(s\w+pop)(.*) /code.php?x=250x250$2;

  # Vertical Banner 120x240
  rewrite ^/(ver\w+ban)(.*) /code.php?x=120x240$2;

  # Full Banner 468x60
  rewrite ^/(f\w+ban)(.*) /code.php?x=468x60$2;

  # Half Banner 234x60
  rewrite ^/(h\w+ban)(.*) /code.php?x=234x60$2;

  # Micro Bar 88x31
  rewrite ^/(m\w+bar)(.*) /code.php?x=88x31$2;

  # Button 1 120x90
  rewrite ^/(b\w+1)(.*) /code.php?x=120x90$2;

  # Button 2 120x60
  rewrite ^/(b\w+2)(.*) /code.php?x=120x60$2;

  # Square Button 125x125
  rewrite ^/(s\w+but)(.*) /code.php?x=125x125$2;

  # Leaderboard 728x90
  rewrite ^/(lea\w+rd)(.*) /code.php?x=728x90$2;

  # Wide Skyscraper 160 x 600
  rewrite ^/(w\w+sk\w+r)(.*) /code.php?x=160x600$2;

  # Skyscraper 120 x 600
  rewrite ^/(sk\w+r)(.*) /code.php?x=120x600$2;

  # Half Page Ad 300 x 600
  rewrite ^/(h\w+g)(.*) /code.php?x=300x600$2;

  # Medium Rectangle 300x250
  rewrite ^/(me)\w+(rec\w+)(.*) /code.php?x=300x250$3;

  # Vertical Rectangle 240x400
  rewrite ^/(ver)\w+(rec)(.*) /code.php?x=240x400$3;

  # Large Rectangle 336x280
  rewrite ^/(large|lrg)(rec)(.*) /code.php?x=336x280$3;

  # Rectangle 180x150
  rewrite ^/(rec)(.*) /code.php?x=180x150$2;

  # Pop Under 720x300
  rewrite ^/(pop)(.*) /code.php?x=720x300$2;
}

# Display Standards - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Video_Standards2.svg

# CGA 320x200
location /cga {
  rewrite ^/(cga)(.*) /code.php?x=320x200$2;
}

# QVGA 320x240
location /qvga {
  rewrite ^/(qvga)(.*) /code.php?x=320x240$2;
}

# VGA 640x480
location /vga {
  rewrite ^/(vga)(.*) /code.php?x=640x480$2;
}

# WVGA 800x480
location /wvga {
  rewrite ^/(wvga)(.*) /code.php?x=800x480$2;
}

# SVGA 1024x600
location /svga {
  rewrite ^/(svga)(.*) /code.php?x=1024x600$2;
}

# WSVGA 1024x600
location /wsvga {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /code.php?x=1024x600;
}

# XGA 1024x768
location /xga {
  rewrite ^/(xga)(.*) /code.php?x=1024x768$2;
}

# WXGA 1280x800
location /wxga {
  rewrite ^/(wxga)(.*) /code.php?x=1280x800$2;
}

# WSXGA 1440x900
location /wsxga {
  rewrite ^/(wsxga)(.*) /code.php?x=1440x900$2;
}

# WUXGA 1920x1200
location /wuxga {
  rewrite ^/(wuxga)(.*) /code.php?x=1920x1200$2;
}

# WQXGA 2560x1600
location /wqxga {
  rewrite ^/(wqxga)(.*) /code.php?x=2560x1600$2;
}

# Video Standards

# NTSC 720x480
location /ntsc {
  rewrite ^/(ntsc)(.*) /code.php?x=720x480$2;
}

# PAL 768x576
location /pal {
  rewrite ^/(pal)(.*) /code.php?x=768x576$2;
}

# HD720 1280x720
location /hd720 {
  rewrite ^/(hd720)(.*) /code.php?x=1280x720$2;
}

# HD1080 1920x1080
location /hd1080 {
  rewrite ^/(hd1080)(.*) /code.php?x=1920x1080$2;
}

location \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

https://github.com/kingkool68/dummyimage

Comment: Nginx does not have per-directory configuration files like Apache. The Nginx configuration is monolithic, although it may be split across multiple files, it starts at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` - use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: Is there any alternative for directory specific rewrite rules, that reside in that directory on ngenx ? We are developing this as a php/wordpress plugin so we do not have access to the root or other server configuration directories.